# (Very) Novice Javascripter Needing Help Understanding Practical Functions

Tags: javascript, function

So I am building an election script that assigns candidates to partys and electorates then assigns them their votes but I am so scrambled so if someone can help me understand what I'm doing, for instance this function here:

```
        class Electorate    {
constructor (newNames) {
this.name = newNames
this.allMyElectorates = []
this.addWinner = []
this.addPartyVotes = []
    }
    addElectorate (...newNames) {
        for(let i=0;i<newNames.length;i++){
            var newElectorate = new Electorate(newNames[i], this.addWinner, 
            this.addPartyVotes)
            this.allMyElectorates.push(newElectorate)
            return newElectorate
    }
}
    addWinner(...newNames){
        theParty = myElection.findParty (partyName)
            if (theParty == undefined){
                myElection.addIndependant (cadidateName)
            }else{
                theCandidate = theParty.findCandidate (candidateName)
            }if (theCandidate == undefined) {
                theParty.addElectorateMP  (candidateName, this)
            }else{
                theCandidate.setElectorate (this)}
        }
    function totalVotes(...newNumbers){
        for(let i=0;i<newNumbers.length;i++){
            var newTotalVotes = new totalVotes(newNumbers[i], this)
            this.addPartyVotes.push(newTotalVotes)
            return newTotalVotes
        }
    }
    function addWinner(...newNames){
        for(let i=0;i<newNumbers.length;i++){
            var addWinner = new Winner(newNames[i], this)
            this.addWinner.push(newWinner)
            return addWinner
        }
    }


}
```

And this is what I'm trying to reference at the moment:

```
 anElectorate = theElection.addElectorate('Auckland Central')
 anElectorate.addWinner('KAYE, Nicola Laura', 'National Party')
 anElectorate.addPartyVotes(329, 85, 10, 486, 3, 2, 6242, 553, 6101, 158, 
                            12652, 1459, 7, 17, 53, 99)
```

I want to create a new function (totalVotes) using data collected from addPartyVotes (in the controller class) that has to to be called from other classes, it has it's variables and I'm pushing it out in an array then returning it so what am I doing wrong?

I've tried asking people in my class and the tutors but I feel like they just fob me off without giving me any real guidance, I'm an engineer not a programmer so this is very difficult to wrap my head around.

Comment: I don't see where `i` is defined for `newNumbers[i]` Please include all relevant source code.

Comment: If you're an engineer then it won't be hard to get to know programming. Programming in any language is applying logic to solve problems. As engineers you must have come across applied maths programming have similar traits. So don't be afraid read little bit more about `JavaScript` and think lot more. Programming is 95% thinking and 5% coding. Also it would be help full if you describe the code a little bit more with comments in your code.

Comment: When I say "engineer" I mean I'm good at building things and maths might as well be russian to me, but your right I just have to find the right way for me to learn like school wants me to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single line or point of code which is breaking your program.
There are countless errors, and will simply not function.

Take a look at this example (JS ES5):

```js
var Electorate = {
  candidates: [],
  init: function() {
    this.candidates = [];
    return this;
  },
  getCandidateByName: function(name) {
    var filter_candidate_by_name = this.candidates.filter(function(d) {
      return d.name === name;
    })[0];
    var index_of_candidate = this.candidates.indexOf(filter_candidate_by_name);
    return this.candidates[index_of_candidate];
  },
  calculateWinner: function() {
    var max_votes = Math.max.apply(Math, this.candidates.map(function(d) {
      return d.votes.length;
    }));
    if (!max_votes || isNaN(max_votes)) return false;
    var records_with_max_votes = this.candidates.filter(function(d) {
      return d.votes.length === max_votes;
    });
    var result = {};
    if (records_with_max_votes.length > 1) {
      result.result = 'Tied';
      result.candidates = records_with_max_votes;
      var list_of_candidate_names = records_with_max_votes.map(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      }).join(', ');
      result.explaination = 'Tied between ' + list_of_candidate_names + ', with a count of ' + max_votes + ' votes each';
    } else if (records_with_max_votes.length === 1) {
      result.result = 'Won';
      result.candidate = records_with_max_votes[0];
      result.explaination = records_with_max_votes[0].name + ' won with a count of ' + max_votes + ' votes';
    }
    return result;
  }
};

var Voter = {
  name: null,
  age: null,
  gender: null,
  init: function(name, age, gender) {
    if (!name || !age || !gender) return false;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    return this;
  }
};

var Candidate = {
  name: null,
  votes: [],
  init: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.votes = [];
    return this;
  },
  castVote: function(voter) {
    this.votes.push(voter);
    return this;
  }
};


var electorate = Object.create(Electorate).init();

electorate.candidates.push(
  Object.create(Candidate).init('Mr. John Smith'),
  Object.create(Candidate).init('Mr. Adam John'),
  Object.create(Candidate).init('Ms. Christina Brown')
);

electorate
  .getCandidateByName('Mr. John Smith')
  .castVote(Object.create(Voter).init('Maria Smith', 38, 'Female'))
  .castVote(Object.create(Voter).init('John Doe', 118, 'Male'))
  .castVote(Object.create(Voter).init('John Doe', 44, 'Male'));

electorate
  .getCandidateByName('Ms. Christina Brown')
  .castVote(Object.create(Voter).init('John Doe', 235, 'Male'))
  .castVote(Object.create(Voter).init('John Doe', 34, 'Male'))
  .castVote(Object.create(Voter).init('John Doe', 22, 'Male'));


console.log(electorate.calculateWinner());
```

You can see that it collects information and takes into account Candidates and Voters which can be created and added to the appropriate data location in the Electorate.

It can then go ahead after all votes are cast, and announce the selected winner or the tied winners.

---

My advice is to brush up on your Javascript knowledge, and try not using ES6 additions.

This is a great resource to brush up on Javascript (for all levels of experience): https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did the code academy site and thought I had a reasonable understanding but then we got given this assignment and it's completely different, the layout and pretty much everything and my mind is completely blown. So I'm going by my gut/google/cut/paste, although google isn't much help because I can't find things in the format my tutor has given us. I'm just terribly confused and freaking out a bit.

Comment: Glad I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Functions cannot take `this` as an argument.

A valid function would look like this:

```
function totalVotes ( vote ) {
   return "something";
}
```

If you can share your entire script pertaining to the voting/election program, I could help guide you and your approach to writing effective code.

Comment: Cheers, I could edit in the whole "electorate" class, the one I'm attempting now, but there are several class files so not sure how I would go about adding it all.

Comment: Could you copy/paste the content of those files? Also, this entire function is not going to work as you may perceive it to.